# How to translate "Drop an image here"?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Help me please, how i can translate text "Drop an image here" in upload pop-up for my language?(for example ru_RU)? Buttons upload, browse for an image - translated with such solution:

```
tinymce.i18n.data.uk_UA['Upload'] = 'My text';
```

But "Drop an image here" can't(
[image]

this text from tinymce.js

```js
define(
  'tinymce.core.ui.DropZone',
  [
    'tinymce.core.ui.Widget',
    'tinymce.core.util.Tools',
    'tinymce.core.ui.DomUtils',
    'global!RegExp'
  ],
  function (Widget, Tools, DomUtils, RegExp) {
    return Widget.extend({
      /**
       * Constructs a instance with the specified settings.
       *
       * @constructor
       * @param {Object} settings Name/value object with settings.
       * @setting {Boolean} multiple True if the dropzone is a multiple control.
       * @setting {Number} maxLength Max length for the dropzone.
       * @setting {Number} size Size of the dropzone in characters.
       */
      init: function (settings) {
        var self = this;

        settings = Tools.extend({
          height: 100,
          text: "Drop an image here",
          multiple: false,
          accept: null // by default accept any files
        }, settings);

        self._super(settings);

        self.classes.add('dropzone');

        if (settings.multiple) {
          self.classes.add('multiple');
        }
      },
```

Comment: where does "DROP AN IMAGE HERE" text come from? if you didn't write that text, perhaps whatever library you are using did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate the text you need to modify the language file for the language(s) you wish to modify.  If I download the current language file for uk_UA I see these two strings on lines 55 and 57

[image]

You need to change the right side of these two string to whatever you want them to be in each language.

Note:  When we add new features to TinyMCE it often takes the community some time to translate the new strings in all the languages we support.  We always welcome assistance with the translation process:  https://www.transifex.com/moxiecode/tinymce/

Answer (score -1):

if you did write and you want to translate it using some library you can use these i think it will help unless like the previous response check the controle constructor
https://github.com/muaz-khan/Translator ||  
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api

Comment: Pretty overkill to use a library to translate a button text, isn't it?